# How create variable name with other variable's value in it?

Tags: python, variables

```
a = "Jack"
b = "Sam"
```

Now I want some way to create this:

```
c_{b value} = 10
```

That means:

```
c_Jack = 10
```

And the following:

```
c_{a value} = 20
```

That means:

```
c_Sam = 20
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Also, __DON'T__

Comment: @matszwecja Why?

Comment: What are you trying to *accomplish* using this technique?  Why isn't using a dictionary a better approach?

Comment: @Guimoute because it is a bad practice. Variable names shouldn't contain data.

Comment: See the linked dupe: use a dict.  Variable variables *are* possible in python, but if you need to ask how to do them, you don't need them (there's a vanishingly small set of cases building debugging tools or stuff interacting with the interpreter in funny ways where I guess they might be needed).  It's a fair (and common) q though, as some languages (e.g. TeX) pretty much require it.

Comment: You can do this: `vars()[f"c_{a}"] = 10; print(c_Jack)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is actually a bad practice to do this. You better to use a `dict`.

BTW, you can do this:

```py
In [3]: a = "Jack"

In [4]: exec(f'c_{a} = 10')

In [5]: c_Jack
Out[5]: 10
```

Comment: 1. Don't answer questions that are clear duplicates. 2. This is a **terrible** idea, especially if there is *any* kind of user-inputted data involved, which there very often will be for this sort of thing. At the very least, you should be sanitizing your input values. Just.... don't.

Comment: Also, this will only work in the global scope

Comment: so many thanks.. thats work but why a bad practice?! i have a loop and i want to use varibales

Comment: @Me8saM Why is it bad practice? 1. You are losing control over your namespace - no IDE will be able to check whether the variable you are trying to use actually exists. 2. You can inject any sort of code during runtime which is __huge__ security risk 3. There are much cleaner, easier ways of achieving same functionalities for 99% of cases.

Again, in case it was not stated enough: __If you had to ask how DO NOT DO THIS.__ If you want to have multiple related variables in a loop, contain them inside some kind of collection like list, set or a dictionary.